# Add user labels in BBPress forums

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

On my website (http://DCJTech.info/) that uses BBPress forums + BuddyPress + Wordpress, how do I add special labels to specific users? For example, Linux.org uses Xenforo and gives particular users labels (http://www.linux.org/threads/gambas-overview.6478/) while some users do not have the blue label/banner (http://www.linux.org/threads/do-you-use-a-vpn.6969/).

Answer (score 0):

can you add in the following html?

```
Staff Writer
```

Comment: I was hoping for an easy plugin. (^u^)